# How to gather characters usage statistics in text file using Unix commands?

Tags: unix, command-line, text, statistics, ocr

I have got a text file created using OCR software - about one megabyte in size.
Some uncommon characters appears all over document and most of them are OCR errors.

I would like find all characters used in document to easily spot errors (like `UNIQ` command but for characters, not for lines).

I am on Ubuntu.
What Unix command I should use to display all characters used in text file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
cat inputfile | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | sort | uniq -c
```

The premise is that the `sed` puts each character in the file onto a line by itself, then the usual `sort | uniq -c` sequence strips out all but one of each unique character that occurs, and provides counts of how many times each occurred.

Also, you could append `| sort -n` to the end of the whole sequence to sort the output by how many times each character occurred.  Example:

```
$ echo hello |  sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
  1 
  1 e
  1 h
  1 o
  2 l
```

Comment: Came here to post exactly this.  But alas I am too slow.  But here's a helpful hint.  At the end, if you want it all on one line, you can add "| perl -pe 'chomp'"

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I was looking for. Clean and simple

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of unwanted/unexpected characters in text files, the creation of which I can't control, so I can start trying to handle them one by one. Unfortunately sort has a problem with that: ```sort: string comparison failed: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
sort: Set LC_ALL='C' to work around the problem.
sort: The strings compared were ‘f’ and ‘\374r’.```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
#
# charcounts - show how many times each code point is used
# Tom Christiansen <tchrist@perl.com>

use open ":utf8";

++$seen{ ord() } for split //;

END {
    for my $cp (sort {$seen{$b} <=> $seen{$a}} keys %seen) {
        printf "%04X %d\n", $cp, $seen{$cp};
    }
}
```

Run on itself, that program produces:

```
$ charcounts /tmp/charcounts | head
0020 46
0065 20
0073 18
006E 15
000A 14
006F 12
0072 11
0074 10
0063 9
0070 9
```

If you want the literal character and/or name of the character, too, that’s easy to add.

If you want something more sophisticated, this program figures out characters by Unicode property. It may be enough for your purposes, and if not, you should be able to adapt it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# unicats - show character distribution by Unicode character property
# Tom Christiansen <tchrist@perl.com>

use strict;
use warnings qw<FATAL all>;

use open ":utf8";

my %cats;

our %Prop_Table;
build_prop_table();

if (@ARGV == 0 && -t STDIN) {
    warn <<"END_WARNING";
$0: reading UTF-8 character data directly from your tty
\tSo please type stuff...
\t and then hit your tty's EOF sequence when done.
END_WARNING

} 

while (<>) {
    for (split(//)) {

        $cats{Total}++;

        if (/\p{ASCII}/) { $cats{ASCII}++   } 
        else             { $cats{Unicode}++ } 

        my $gcat   = get_general_category($_);
        $cats{$gcat}++;

        my $subcat = get_general_subcategory($_);
        $cats{$subcat}++;

    } 
} 

my $width = length $cats{Total};

my $mask = "%*d %s\n";

for my $cat(qw< Total ASCII Unicode >) { 
    printf $mask, $width => $cats{$cat} || 0, $cat; 
}
print "\n";

my @catnames = qw[
    L Lu Ll Lt Lm Lo
    N Nd Nl No
    S Sm Sc Sk So
    P Pc Pd Ps Pe Pi Pf Po
    M Mn Mc Me
    Z Zs Zl Zp
    C Cc Cf Cs Co Cn
];

#for my $cat (sort keys %cats) {
for my $cat (@catnames) {
    next if length($cat) > 2;
    next unless $cats{$cat};

    my $prop = length($cat) == 1 
                 ? ( " " . q<\p> .   $cat          )
                 : (       q<\p> . "{$cat}" . "\t" )
             ;

    my $desc = sprintf("%-6s %s", $prop, $Prop_Table{$cat});

    printf $mask, $width => $cats{$cat}, $desc;
} 

exit;

sub get_general_category {
    my $_ = shift();
    return "L" if /\pL/;
    return "S" if /\pS/;
    return "P" if /\pP/;
    return "N" if /\pN/;
    return "C" if /\pC/;
    return "M" if /\pM/;
    return "Z" if /\pZ/;

    die "not reached one: $_";
} 

sub get_general_subcategory {
    my $_ = shift();

    return "Lu" if /\p{Lu}/;
    return "Ll" if /\p{Ll}/;
    return "Lt" if /\p{Lt}/;
    return "Lm" if /\p{Lm}/;
    return "Lo" if /\p{Lo}/;

    return "Mn" if /\p{Mn}/;
    return "Mc" if /\p{Mc}/;
    return "Me" if /\p{Me}/;

    return "Nd" if /\p{Nd}/;
    return "Nl" if /\p{Nl}/;
    return "No" if /\p{No}/;

    return "Pc" if /\p{Pc}/;
    return "Pd" if /\p{Pd}/;
    return "Ps" if /\p{Ps}/;
    return "Pe" if /\p{Pe}/;
    return "Pi" if /\p{Pi}/;
    return "Pf" if /\p{Pf}/;
    return "Po" if /\p{Po}/;

    return "Sm" if /\p{Sm}/;
    return "Sc" if /\p{Sc}/;
    return "Sk" if /\p{Sk}/;
    return "So" if /\p{So}/;

    return "Zs" if /\p{Zs}/;
    return "Zl" if /\p{Zl}/;
    return "Zp" if /\p{Zp}/;

    return "Cc" if /\p{Cc}/;
    return "Cf" if /\p{Cf}/;
    return "Cs" if /\p{Cs}/;
    return "Co" if /\p{Co}/;
    return "Cn" if /\p{Cn}/;

    die "not reached two: <$_> " . sprintf("U+%vX", $_);

}

sub build_prop_table { 

    for my $line (<<"End_of_Property_List" =~ m{ \S .* \S }gx) {

       L           Letter
       Lu          Uppercase_Letter
       Ll          Lowercase_Letter
       Lt          Titlecase_Letter
       Lm          Modifier_Letter
       Lo          Other_Letter

       M           Mark  (combining characters, including diacritics)
       Mn          Nonspacing_Mark
       Mc          Spacing_Mark
       Me          Enclosing_Mark

       N           Number
       Nd          Decimal_Number (also Digit)
       Nl          Letter_Number
       No          Other_Number

       P           Punctuation
       Pc          Connector_Punctuation
       Pd          Dash_Punctuation
       Ps          Open_Punctuation
       Pe          Close_Punctuation
       Pi          Initial_Punctuation (may behave like Ps or Pe depending on usage)
       Pf          Final_Punctuation (may behave like Ps or Pe depending on usage)
       Po          Other_Punctuation

       S           Symbol
       Sm          Math_Symbol
       Sc          Currency_Symbol
       Sk          Modifier_Symbol
       So          Other_Symbol

       Z           Separator
       Zs          Space_Separator
       Zl          Line_Separator
       Zp          Paragraph_Separator

       C           Other (means not L/N/P/S/Z)
       Cc          Control (also Cntrl)
       Cf          Format
       Cs          Surrogate   (not usable)
       Co          Private_Use
       Cn          Unassigned

End_of_Property_List

            my($short_prop, $long_prop) = $line =~ m{ 
                \b 
                 ( \p{Lu}  \p{Ll}   ? ) 
                \s + 
                 ( \p{Lu} [\p{L&}_] + )
                \b
            }x;

            $Prop_Table{$short_prop} = $long_prop;

    }

}
```

For example:

```
$ unicats book.txt
2357232 Total
2357199 ASCII
     33 Unicode

1604949  \pL   Letter
  74455 \p{Lu}   Uppercase_Letter
1530485 \p{Ll}   Lowercase_Letter
      9 \p{Lo}   Other_Letter
  10676  \pN   Number
  10676 \p{Nd}   Decimal_Number
  19679  \pS   Symbol
  10705 \p{Sm}   Math_Symbol
   8365 \p{Sc}   Currency_Symbol
    603 \p{Sk}   Modifier_Symbol
      6 \p{So}   Other_Symbol
 111899  \pP   Punctuation
   2996 \p{Pc}   Connector_Punctuation
   6145 \p{Pd}   Dash_Punctuation
  11392 \p{Ps}   Open_Punctuation
  11371 \p{Pe}   Close_Punctuation
  79995 \p{Po}   Other_Punctuation
 548529  \pZ   Separator
 548529 \p{Zs}   Space_Separator
  61500  \pC   Other
  61500 \p{Cc}   Control
```

Comment: Looks too clean for pearl :-) Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @Hali, judge not the programming language for cleanliless, but the programmer. Any programmer who generates messy code is an idiot and a menace.

Answer (score 0):

As far as using *nix commands, the answer above is good, but it doesn't get usage stats.

However, if you actually want stats (like the rarest used, median, most used, etc) on the file, this Python should do it.

```
def get_char_counts(fname):
    f = open(fname)
    usage = {}
    for c in f.read():
        if c not in usage:
            usage.update({c:1})
        else:
            usage[c] += 1
    return usage
```

Comment: But there are stats too in above answers. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @Hali - Didn't see the above edit (And the answer needed a chunk of Python anyway ;)